# Shopify - adding specific class to homepage only

Tags: shopify, liquid

In Shopify, trying to add a class ONLY to the homepage .has-intro

Right now, if i add .has-intro to the theme.liquid where the  is it applies it to EVERY page (product page, checkout, etc).

Is there a way through liquid to add in .has-intro just to the homepage?

Comment: use liquid `{% if %}` to check the `tempate` and if it is `index` add the class

Comment: Thanks so much! Was able to do it pretty much how you had described, like this:

<html class="no-js{% if template == 'index' %} show-intro{% endif %}" lang="{{ request.locale.iso_code }}">

.show-intro is the class that i only wanted displayed on the homepage index page. 

hope this helps others in the future!